# What physics does the Super Proton Proton Collider intend to explore in the $\lesssim 100\:\mathrm{TeV}$ range?

Tags: particle-physics, beyond-the-standard-model, accelerator-physics, particle-accelerators

[Chinese scientists](http://www.chinadaily.com.cn/china/2015-10/29/content_22304147.htm) have completed an initial conceptual design of a super giant particle collider which will be bigger and more powerful than any particle accelerator on Earth. With a circumference of $50$ to $100\:\mathrm{km}$ the proposed Chinese accelerator, the [Super Proton Proton Collider (SPPC)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.03224) (which will eventually replace the proposed [Circular Electron Positron Collider (CEPC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_Electron_Positron_Collider)) will be a $100\:\mathrm{TeV}$ proton-proton collider.

What are the new expected discoveries (resonances) in the region (parameter space) up to $100\:\mathrm{TeV}$ ?

Answer (score 5):

[The main goal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_Electron_Positron_Collider#Physics_program) is to measure accurately the  parameters of the Higgs boson and its interactions. It is a proposal to repeat what was done with the SPS and its discovery of W and Z  and electron positron collider LEP built to solidify accurately the standard model parameters.

New physics will come up with deviations from the standard model, but these deviations can only be established with accurate measurements and it is only leptons with their clear initial  interactions that can provide them.

They then want to repeat the SPS LEP program by building a proton proton discovery machine in the same tunnel which will explore energies of 100TeV, giving access to supersymmetry and [string phenomenology expectations.](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/string+phenomenology) , and of course any new surprises nature may have for us.

Comment: I find a circular electron-positron collider surprising, especially given that a collaboration led by the Japanese is exploring a possible Higgs-factory at the [International Linear Collider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Linear_Collider). Electrons lose energy due to bremsstrahlung quite quickly in a circular collider, but I guess it should be feasible if the energies considered are not far from the LEP, and with a significantly higher tunnel radius.

Comment: The point of the above comment was to induce comments from you, on the matter :-)

Comment: @Siva  To run 50 TeV colliding  protons it will need the much larger radius , and  it will be OK for electrons.  It is a competition , the ILC is the next project of CERN  . Unless new methods of acceleration are developed it is not probable that new circular accelerators will be built at CERN as what with the mountains and the lake the space is not enough. If China foots a lot of the bill for the tunnel the project gives a future to accelerator physics. My opinion has been for a long time that new methods of acceleration have to be developed, and maybe with nanotechnology it will happen.

Comment: @annav: ILC is not a project at CERN, it is the International Linear Collider initially foreseen in Japan (but still not decided). The future of CERN is the FCC, the Future Circular Collider, a hadron collider with a centre-of-mass energy of the order of 100 TeV in a new 80-100 km circumference tunnel. See https://fcc.web.cern.ch/Pages/About.aspx

Comment: @Paganini Thanks, I am out of date on ILC; though this FCC still seems to me an impossible goal thinking of the land. Already the LEPtunnel was very deep into the mountain.

Comment: @Siva it seems I am wrong about the ILC being a CERN project, see the comment bt Paganini

Comment: CERN has its own project for a linear collider up to $3~$TeV CoM based on warm technology, called Compact Linear Collider, or CLIC. The CLIC workshop collects every year about 300 participants from all over the world. Will CLIC or FCC be the future of CERN, nobody knows right now. Both the studies are being carried on in parallel with a similar amount of allocated resources.

Answer (score 0):

The expected discoveries (resonances) in the energy range up to $100~$TeV depends on the theory that you decide to believe in.

None of the theories beyond the Standard Model has been experimentally validated yet. If you only believe in the Standard Model, then there are no new resonances expected as the theory was completed with the discovery of the Higgs boson.

Still the Standard Model is not totally satisfying as it leaves many open questions (matter antimatter asymmetry, candidates for dark matter, fine tunings of some of its internal parameters, ...) so we expect to have something more.

Within the framework of the Standard Model, a lepton collider at a centre of mass energy up to $\sim350~$GeV offers a number of very precise tests which would eventually allow to discover unexpected deviation or inconsistencies. According to M. Mangano a proton collider at $100~$TeV would open additional channels such as:

- Direct access to $ttH$ and $HHH$ couplings
- High-statistics and sensitivity for very rare decays like $H\rightarrow μ^+μ^–$ and $H\rightarrow Zγ$

In general compared to the high luminosity upgrade of the LHC, a $100~$TeV machine would come with a much higher statistics, which in turn gives access to different kinematical regions, with better control of backgrounds and experimental/theoretical systematics.

I would suggest to have a look at the European studies for Future Circular Colliders (FCC) which are the competitors of the Chinese designs. As starting point here is a link for a series of academic lectures that have been given at CERN in Feb 2016: https://indico.cern.ch/event/472105/. They cover theoretical physics, detectors and accelerators designs. Note that the **recordings** of the lectures have been uploaded as well!

Comment: Not all discoveries are resonances. Eg SUSY probably wouldn't be discovered by a resonance

Comment: @innisfree ...especially if it wont be discovered at all :(  Anyway I totally agree, in that case the parenthesis means $\supset$. By the way, I just copied it from the question, so you could comment there as well.