# Collision of electron and proton of high energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, collision

What will happen when proton and electron with high energy like in 100 TeV collide?

Comment: There are no 100 TeV accelerators, although CERN wants to build one. We don't know what *will* happen, but I'm sure there are plenty of particle theorists who have ideas--many ideas.

Comment: Just for one collision, I would say that by far the most probability is that the electron pass through. If you are exclusively interested in collision with components, I would guess it produces half of what produces proton-proton collision, + 1 electron.  ;-)

Comment: @BillN: So what if CERN can't do it? There are plenty more [accelerators in the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroparticle_physics) that can; AGN and supernova remnants, for instance.

Comment: Probably also related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/233373/

Comment: Personally, I don't think this question is unclear, seems to be pretty clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

It is called [deep inelastic scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_inelastic_scattering).

> Deep inelastic scattering is the name given to a process used to probe the insides of hadrons (particularly the baryons, such as protons and neutrons), using electrons, muons and neutrinos. It provided the first convincing evidence of the reality of quarks, which up until that point had been considered by many to be a purely mathematical phenomenon

[image: deep inel]

> Deep inelastic scattering of a lepton on a hadron, at leading order in perturbative expansion. Where h is a hadron (proton or neutron) composed of three constituent quarks and a sea of quarks/antiquarks, as depicted [here](http://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/largehadroncolliderfaq/whats-a-proton-anyway/)

[image: proton]  . The incoming from the left l (lepton, electron in this case) scatters off a  q (quark)  by exchanging a photon (  γ , the star is to remind it is [virtual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_particle)).

I think it was Feynman who said "to see what a watch is made of one does not throw one watch on another watch and count the gears flying off. One takes a screw driver".# Leptons with their weak interactions are the equivalent of the screw driver. Protons on protons , with their quark and gluon contents need complicated modeling to get any useful information on quark quark scattering, i.e. elementary particle scattering. Leptons , among which electrons, reproduce at elementary particle level the Rutherford experiment, exploring the core of the  nucleons.

Now it is much harder to get a center of mass energy for an electron+ proton to 100 TeV, even with linear colliders than proton proton colliders like the LHC which  is the reason exploratory machines are proton proton. The  proposed international linear collider [ILC](http://www.linearcollider.org/ILC/What-is-the-ILC/Facts-and-figures) , electrons on positrons, will be exploring the Higgs region with energies of 0.5 TeV and upgraded 1 TeV, whereas the Higgs was found by a 7 TeV  [LHC](http://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/largehadroncolliderfaq/introduction-to-the-large-hadron-collider/) proton proton collider. The future exploratory machine is proposed again to  be a [proton proton one](http://profmattstrassler.com/2014/03/03/a-100-tev-proton-proton-collider/) .

> What will happen when proton and electron with high energy like in 100 TeV collide?

If it can be technologically achieved, there will be an opportunity for an exploration of the behavior of lepton quark scattering with the possibility of very accurate measurements and smaller dependence on phenomenological models, than in proton proton scattering. It is expected that particles predicted by [supersymmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersymmetry) and possibly [string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersymmetry) effects will become established, if they are there.

---

# I tried to find the source for this by googling, but could not. (Maybe        I heard it at a lecture, I sat through some summer school lectures
 by Feynman in 1964 and workshop lectures in 1981)